# MYSQL: inserting error

Tags: mysql

MYSQL Problem inserting Certain type of Text

when i try to insert this for example:

```
INSERT INTO `Attacks_key` 
  (`Event_Key` ,`Variable` ,`Value` ,`Impact` ,`Tags`)
    VALUES 
  ('111', 'REQUEST', ' mysql_real_escape ', '222', 'xss, csrf, id, rfe, lfi');
```

its inserted But when I try to insert this :

```
INSERT INTO `Attacks_key` 
 (`Event_Key` ,`Variable` ,`Value` ,`Impact` ,`Tags`) 
   VALUES 
 ('111', 'REQUEST', 'mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); ', '222', 'xss, csrf, id, rfe, lfi');
```

MYSQL display this message :

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'username']); ', '222', 'xss, csrf, id, rfe, lfi')' at line 1

and this is my php code

```
$user="root";
$password="*";
$database="*";
mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$sql = "SELECT `Key_id` FROM `Event` ORDER BY `Key_id` DESC LIMIT 1";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$EventKey= $row['Key_id'];
$query="INSERT INTO `PHPLOGS`.`Attacks_key` (`Event_Key` ,`Variable` ,`Value` ,`Impact` ,`Tags`) VALUES ('$EventKey', '$getname', '$getvalue', '$getimpec', '$gettags');";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
```

and the input 'mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);  from the user

Can someone help

thanks

Comment: You have nested quoted sections `'mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); '` contains `'username'` - yet another problem you would not have with prepared statements!

Comment: are you really trying to insert the literal value `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])` or is that supposed to be PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're inserting `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);` literally, then escape the single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO `Attacks_key` 
 (`Event_Key` ,`Variable` ,`Value` ,`Impact` ,`Tags`) 
   VALUES 
 ('111', 'REQUEST', 'mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[\'username\']); ', '222', 'xss, csrf, id, rfe, lfi');
```

Comment: but Ruel im design my own PHPIDS (PHP-Intrusion Detection System) and  this input form user that try to hack my website so im trying to save all information to mySQl database so how can i inert it  if icanot change it to   "'mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[\'username\']); "

Comment: and this my php code  $user="root";
 $password="*";
 $database="*";
 mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);
 @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
 $sql = "SELECT `Key_id` FROM `Event` ORDER BY `Key_id` DESC LIMIT 1";
 $result =mysql_query($sql);
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 $EventKey= $row['Key_id'];
 $query="INSERT INTO `PHPLOGS`.`Attacks_key` (`Event_Key` ,`Variable` ,`Value` ,`Impact` ,`Tags`) VALUES ('$EventKey', '$getname', '$getvalue', '$getimpec', '$gettags');";

 mysql_query($query);
 mysql_close();

Answer (score 1):

Try

`$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO Attacks_key (Event_Key ,Variable ,Value ,Impact ,Tags) VALUES ('111', 'REQUEST', '%s', '222', 'xss, csrf, id, rfe, lfi');",
            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));`

There's a conflict of `'` in that part of the statement with `'username'`

Have a look at [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Have you actually tried that?  How does MySQL know that it must interpret `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);` as a string?

Comment: I have not tried it, and am unsure how to do parameterised queries in PHP, however the conflict is in the quotation marks. The answer was intended to highlight that more than to provide a cut/paste code solution, I should have made that clearer. Ideally you would assign the escaped value to a variable and use the variable in the query.

Answer (score 0):

As you should really really switch to PDO instead of the deprecated mysql_ functions you could use [PDO::quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

> PDO::quote() places quotes around the input string (if required) and
>   escapes special characters within the input string, using a quoting
>   style appropriate to the underlying driver.

However, the preferred way of doing queries is by using prepared queries, and in that case you wouldn't have the quote escaping problem anyways.  Again quoting from the php manual page for PDO:;quote

> If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are
>   strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements
>   with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate
>   user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound
>   parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL
>   injection, but are often much faster to execute than interpolated
>   queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form
>   of the query.

If for whatever reason PDO isn't an option, there's [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) with a similar functionalty.